# How to improve accuracy face detect in Emgu cv using g.net

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv

I am practicing face recognition using Emgucv version 3.1.0.2282 in winform .net. Is there a way to help with facial recognition more accurately?

For example, there is an image that I cannot recognize faces, but after I have successfully detected a few other photos, I recognized a face in the image I have not detected a face before.

I am not understanding that and should I detect the face according to the original or edited photo to grayscale.
Thank you so much.